# Adobe Illustrator - Variable data on SVG images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphics, adobe-illustrator

I found a Variableimporter script for AI but based on youtube vidoes, I can set an image as dynamic only when it is PNG file.

Does anyone figured out how to use Variable data on SVG objects?

Link to [Variableimporter](https://github.com/Silly-V/Adobe-Illustrator/blob/master/Variable%20Importer/VariableImporter.jsx)

I tried to create a dynamic image on ai and svg objects, both did not worked.

Comment: Remember that _"did not worked (sic)"_ is never a sufficiently detailed description of what happened when you tried something.  Did you get an error message?  What were the expected vs actual results?  And give us your best explanation as to why you think what you did would cause the expected results.

Comment: I cannot press the "create dynamic object" button in AI.
I expect to create a dynamic object which will change according to variable.
I want to use this script to change text and graphic object according to variable drawn from CSV file.
Text variable works fine. Unfortunately I cannot set as dynamic object my graphic desing object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It's actually possible to put any type of image as data type.
I used wrong file type in my template. I had an SVG file in there and i wanted to link it with .ai type.
To create dynamic image, file format of images you want as variables, must be the same as in your template.